# Associating DB3 with Xamarin Forms app

Tags: ios, sqlite, file, xamarin.forms, info.plist

I'm having some difficulty associating a .db3 file with my iOS project of my Xamarin Forms app. Ideally I would like the user to click on a file type of .db3 and for it to open my app.
I've edited the Info.plist to contain:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
      <array>
        <string>**********.png</string>
      </array>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>*******</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Viewer</string>
      <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
      <string>Alternate</string>
      <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
      <array>
        <string>public.db3</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong in my code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exact problem did you facing ?  where's your code about `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

Comment: The problem is the file doesn't open with my app. The code above when altered slightly works with pdf, I'm overriding HandleOpenURL in my AppDelgate class to handle what to do with the file once opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this worked as a solution:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
      <string>any.png</string>
      <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
      <array>
        <string>com.proj.name.db3</string>
      </array>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>DB3 Custom data type</string>
      <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
      <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
  </array>

  <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
      <string>Database file import and export</string>
      <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
      <array>
        <string>public.text</string>
      </array>
      <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
      <string>com.proj.name.db3</string>
      <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
      <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <string>db3</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </array>
```